# "Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed" when using a SqlDataReader

Tags: c#, sqldatareader

1) I have the following codes:

```
private static sqlDataReader gCandidateList = null;

public SqlDataReader myCandidateList
{
    set
    {
        gCandidateList = value;
    }
    get
    {
        return gCandidateList;
    }
}
```

2) In FormA I have:

```
sqlConn.ConnectionString = mySettings.myConnString;
sqlConn.Open();
SqlCommand cmdAvailableCandidate = new SqlCommand(tempString, sqlConn);
SqlDataReader drAvailableCandidate = cmdAvailableCandidate.ExecuteReader();
mySettings.myCandidateList = drAvailableCandidate;
sqlConn.Close();
```

3) In FormB I want to reuse the data saved in myCandidatList so I use:

```
SqlDataReader drCandidate = mySettings.myCandidateList;
drCandidate.Read();
```

4) I then got the error "Invalide attempt to call Read when reader is closed."

5) I tried mySettings.myCandidateList.Read() in (3) above and again received the same error message.

6) How can I re-open SqlDataReader drCandidate to read data?

7) Would appreciate very much for advise and help, please.

Comment: A static DataReader is never a good idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't read reader once the connection is `closed` or `disposed`. If you want to use those rows (fetch result) later in your code you need to create a `List` or `DataTable`.

For instance,

```
System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
dt.Load(drAvailableCandidate);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the datareader at later stage, you have to specify the same as a parameter to the ExecuteReader Method. Your code in FormA should be changed as below.

```
sqlConn.ConnectionString = mySettings.myConnString;  
sqlConn.Open();  
SqlCommand cmdAvailableCandidate = new SqlCommand(tempString, sqlConn);  
SqlDataReader drAvailableCandidate = cmdAvailableCandidate.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);  
mySettings.myCandidateList = drAvailableCandidate;  
sqlConn.Close();
```

Make sure to dispose the datareader once it is used, as the connection to the database will be held open till the datareader is closed. Better change your code in FormB as below.

```
using (mySettings.myCandidateList)
{
mySettings.myCandidateList.Read();  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're closing the connection before you attempt to read from the reader.  That won't work.

Answer (score 0):

When you call Close on the `SqlConnection` object (`sqlConn.Close();`) it closes the connection and your data reader.  That is why you are getting the error when you try to read from your `SqlDataReader` from FormB.

What you need to do is change the definition of your `myCandidateList` property to instead return a representation of the data that you have extracted from the your `drAvailableCandidate` reader.

Essentially what you need to do is iterate through the rows in the `drAvailableCandidate` object, extract the values and cache them in your property for later retrieval.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the answers already given, if you're using async/await then it's easy to get caught out with this by not awaiting an operation inside a using block of a SqlConnection. For example, doing the following can give the reported error

```
public Task GetData()
{
    using(new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        return SomeAsyncOperation();
    }
}
```

The problem here is we're not awaiting the operation inside the using, therefore it's being disposed of before we actually execute the underling async operation. Fairly obvious, but has caught me out before.

The correct thing to do being to await inside the using.

```
public async Task GetData()
{
    using(new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        await SomeAsyncOperation();
    }
}
```